# Python Flask countdown timer not work syncing

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-socketio

I write my countdown timer works successfully but when i page refresh countdown timer resets. Countdown timer doesn't start if i don't open page and not sync work all clients.

**This is my server-side python flask code :**

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,render_template_string
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit

app = Flask(__name__) 
app.config['SECRET KEY'] = 'random'
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.route('/') 
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('test_timer')
def Timer(seconds=3600):
    def hms(seconds): # hour minute second function
        h = seconds // 3600
        m = seconds % 3600 // 60
        s = seconds % 3600 % 60
        return '{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(h, m, s)
    
    for i in range(seconds):
        emit('test_timer_reply',hms(seconds-i),broadcast=True)
        socketio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,debug=True)
```

**This is my client-side javascript code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var socket = io();
            socket.emit('test_timer')
            socket.on('test_timer_reply', function(receiving_data) {
            console.log(receiving_data);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I get the timer to work before I open the page?

How do I ensure that the timer is not reset when I refresh the page?

How do I the timer to work synchronously(countdown time it will be same all clients) on all clients?